# Pandemic Legacy Season 1 September: Where to search if the conditions can’t be met?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

In September we are supposed to

> search for the paranoid soldier in a faded city with military base.

...but we don’t have one! We have the former and the latter, but not both at the same time. We could build one, but then the story does not make much sense, as we could not rediscover something lost in a place we just built!

Anyway... is that the way to go? Build and search?

Comment: This is a board game, not a role-playing game: if the rules mandate that such a such a condition it must be met, independently on the story! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Compiled FAQ](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1470601/compiled-faq-spoilers-hidden-each-month-hidden-sep) on BGG, taken from the July spoiler:

> What if there are no research stations in faded cities?
>
> You will need to build one (or use Field Hospital ) if you wish to attempt the search.

So similarly, in September you'll need to build a military base in one of your faded cities.

I don't know what the thematic explanation is, but I'm sure you could retcon something - building a military base is actually commandeering an existing facility, or it just gives you the necessary infrastructure to find the soldier in the region, or he congregates to the base, or something.